# Recognize a specific sound in a conversation with Windows Azure services

Tags: java, python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, sound-recognition

I would like to know if is possible create a service with Cognitive Services of Windows Azure that allow me to recognize one specific sound in a conversation (provided by a live stream in internet) and how make it.
I already know basic techniques of Machine Learning, but I never implemented something like this, anyway I would like to use Cognitive Services to make it in a simple and efficient way.
This task will be linked with other task like a chain of events, so I should use something that provide SKD for java or Python.
Did somebody know how can I make it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Now, there is a new preview cognitive service named [`Speaker Recognition API`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/), which you can use it to implement your needs for recognizing a specific sound in a conversation, please see the offical [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/home) to know the details. And there is only REST APIs for this service by now, not SDKs for specific programming languages like Java/Python. So please move to the REST API reference [website](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797) to learn how to use it.

Hope it helps.